# How to create new account using servlets

Tags: java, design-patterns, servlets

I want to know how can I create new account using servlets in post method?

I'm currently following MVC design pattern, and I want to know if I pass the required data to register new account from JSP page, then how can I get that data in post method? As request.getParameter() method returning me `null`. How can I know that post method is calling to create new account?

How can I pass all the relevant user information from servlets to model class for registering data to the database table?

Comment: how can we know, if you have provided no code

Answer (score 1):

If `request.getParamter()` returns null, then the problem needs to be solved somewhere else. Maybe wrong form encoding? Maybe wrong parameter name? It's basically not that hard. A HTML form like this in the JSP..

```
<form action="register" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

..in combination with a `Servlet` which is mapped in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/register` and the following in the `doPost()` method..

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

..should just work. Then you just create a new model class, fill it with those values and pass it to the DAO class to persist it in the DB.

I suggest to get yourself through those excellent basic JSP/Servlet tutorials to get yourself started: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

You may also find this [basic DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful, the 2nd part exist of a [basic JSP/Servlet example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html) handling a simple use case of "Register user", exactly what you need.